# Internal Server Error when I try to use HTTPS protocol for traefik backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, consul, traefik

My setup is ELB --https--> traefik --https--> service

I get back a 500 Internal Server Error from traefik on every request. It doesn't appear the request ever makes it to the service. The service is running Apache with access logging and I see no incoming requests logged. I am able to curl the service directly and receive an expected response. Both traefik and the service are running in Docker containers. I am also able to use port 80 all the way through with success, and I can use https to traefik and port 80 to the service. I get an error from apache, but it does go all the way through.

traefik.toml

```
logLevel = "DEBUG"
RootCAs = [ "/etc/certs/ca.pem" ]
#InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/etc/certs/cert.pem"
      keyFile = "/etc/certs/key.pem"
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

[web]
address = ":8080"

[traefikLog]

[accessLog]

[consulCatalog]
endpoint = "127.0.0.1:8500"
domain = "consul.localhost"
exposedByDefault = false
prefix = "traefik"
```

The tags used for the consul service:

```
"traefik.enable=true",
"traefik.protocol=https",
"traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true",
"traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https",
"traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https",
"traefik.frontend.rule=Host:hostname"
```

The debug output from traefik for each request:

```
time="2018-04-08T02:46:36Z"
level=debug
msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: begin ServeHttp on request"
Request="{"Method":"GET","URL":{"Scheme":"","Opaque":"","User":null,"Host":"","Path":"/","RawPath":"","ForceQuery":false,"RawQuery":"","Fragment":""},"Proto":"HTTP/1.1","ProtoMajor":1,"ProtoMinor":1,"Header":{"Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"],"Accept-Language":["en-US,en;q=0.9"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0"],"Cookie":["__utmc=80117009; PHPSESSID=64c928bgf265fgqdqqbgdbuqso; _ga=GA1.2.573328135.1514428072; messagesUtk=d353002175524322ac26ff221d1e80a6; __hstc=27968611.cbdd9ce39324304b461d515d0a8f4cb0.1523037648547.1523037648547.1523037648547.1; __hssrc=1; hubspotutk=cbdd9ce39324304b461d515d0a8f4cb0; __utmz=80117009.1523037658.5.2.utmcsr=|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; __utma=80117009.573328135.1514428072.1523037658.1523128344.6"],"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":["1"],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.81 Safari/537.36"],"X-Amzn-Trace-Id":["Root=1-5ac982a8-b9615451a35258e3fd2a825d"],"X-Forwarded-For":["76.105.255.147"],"X-Forwarded-Port":["443"],"X-Forwarded-Proto":["https"]},"ContentLength":0,"TransferEncoding":null,"Host”:”hostname”,”Form":null,"PostForm":null,"MultipartForm":null,"Trailer":null,"RemoteAddr":"10.200.20.130:4880","RequestURI":"/","TLS":null}"

time="2018-04-08T02:46:36Z" level=debug 
msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: Forwarding this request to URL" 
Request="{"Method":"GET","URL":{"Scheme":"","Opaque":"","User":null,"Host":"","Path":"/","RawPath":"","ForceQuery":false,"RawQuery":"","Fragment":""},"Proto":"HTTP/1.1","ProtoMajor":1,"ProtoMinor":1,"Header":{"Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"],"Accept-Language":["en-US,en;q=0.9"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0"],"Cookie":["__utmc=80117009; PHPSESSID=64c928bgf265fgqdqqbgdbuqso; _ga=GA1.2.573328135.1514428072; messagesUtk=d353002175524322ac26ff221d1e80a6; __hstc=27968611.cbdd9ce39324304b461d515d0a8f4cb0.1523037648547.1523037648547.1523037648547.1; __hssrc=1; hubspotutk=cbdd9ce39324304b461d515d0a8f4cb0; __utmz=80117009.1523037658.5.2.utmcsr=|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; __utma=80117009.573328135.1514428072.1523037658.1523128344.6"],"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":["1"],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.81 Safari/537.36"],"X-Amzn-Trace-Id":["Root=1-5ac982a8-b9615451a35258e3fd2a825d"],"X-Forwarded-For":["76.105.255.147"],"X-Forwarded-Port":["443"],"X-Forwarded-Proto":["https"]},"ContentLength":0,"TransferEncoding":null,"Host”:”hostname”,”Form":null,"PostForm":null,"MultipartForm":null,"Trailer":null,"RemoteAddr":"10.200.20.130:4880","RequestURI":"/","TLS":null}" ForwardURL="https://10.200.115.53:443"
```

assume "hostname" is the correct host name. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: It appears this is some sort of certificate issue. After turning on debug level logging in Apache I'm seeing this error `ACCEPT_SR_KEY_EXCH:sslv3 alert bad certificate (SSL alert number 42)`

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem come from `"traefik.protocol=https"`, remove this tag.

Also you can remove `traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https` because it's useless: this tag create a redirection to `https` entrypoint but your frontend is already on the `https` entry point (`"traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https"`)

Comment: When I remove "traefik.protocol=https" traefik starts making http requests to the backend service. This does connect with the service but apache throws an error as it was expecting https on port 443

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm the only one who had this problem, considering there's a lot of documentation that suggests using `"traefik.protocol=https"`, but I greatly appreciate this, it solved my "Internal Server Error"/500 issue.